# What is the difference between ' 2>&1 ' and '>'?

Tags: linux, command-line, redirection

If 2>&1 redirects the stderr to the stdout, isn't that what just '>' does? So does '2>&1' and '>' have the same meaning or are they different in some way?
Explanations about redirections seem to revolve around the difference between what each of them mean but does not say if '2>&1' and '>' are the same.
Can someone tell me where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` has a meaning on its own. It is a redirection operator.

`2>` may be redirecting `stderr`, but `stderr` is not the only output from a task. There is also `stdout` which is 1 and there are also other places you could redirect to.

For example `>myOutput.txt` will redirect output (I believe only `stdout` by default) from that task to your file.

Then there is `1>stdOut.txt` which explicitly redirects **only** `stdout` to the output file.

By extension you could also do `2>stdErr.txt`

The reason to do `2>&1` is to redirect `stderr` to the same stream as `stdout` so that you only have one stream as an output from the command. Then that combined output can be redirected as one command.

So rather than

```
myCommand 1>stdOut.txt 2>stdErr.txt
```

You can do

```
myCommand 1>combinedOut.txt  2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks man. Before asking the question I printed out the output into the terminal in which case both seemed to have the same answer. Now i tried writing to a file with the > and the 2>&1 and it is very different.

Comment: @randomSapien yep, by default both stderr and stdout will go to your console so it will look the same, it's when you need to actually send that output somewhere that you find out that they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

> So rather than
>
> ```
> myCommand 1>stdOut.txt 2>stdErr.txt
> ```
>
> You can do
>
> ```
> myCommand 2>&1 1>combinedOut.txt
> ```

… it is not really correct… if you want to send stderr and stdout at the same place, the `2>&1` has to be used at the end of the command.

Here, the stderr is sent at your stdout not redirected (console), and the stdout is sent to the file with no effect on the stderr.

Comment: Okay, thanks man. For anyone wondering i got the result using `command > file.txt 2>&1`